# Date Format to index in lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I am using lucene to search date ranges. I want to know how should I take date to index it.
When I want to index it in all resolution ie. Year,Month,Day,Hour,Minute,second,Millisecond

Answer (score 0):

The data you're indexing provides time information up to the Millisecond? The only sort of data that I can think of that provides that sort of precise information is something like a list of benchmarking results or maybe you're searching through best times of an auto race or something.

At this point I don't think you should use Lucene if you're only looking to search date ranges. A relational database performs quite well for this.

You can still keep Lucene for full-text search stuff, and use something else for date ranges (MySQL).

Here's just a reference from Lucene's site:

> In a query form, fields which are
>   general text should use the query
>   parser. All others, such as **date
>   ranges**, keywords, etc. are better
>   added directly through the query API.

Comment: i used GregorianCalendar Object for taking date, my que is: is there any better way to read a date. Here I am including object taht i used.                                       GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(2004,1,1,1,1,1);
java.util.Date lowerDate =new java.util.Date((startDate.getTimeInMillis()));